# take select request from django from

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-forms, django-views

I have made a select django form with list of images for each user.

How do I take that select request in my views.py ?

I have only managed to create correct that select list but I need to take that select request. But I don't know how.

models.py

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    upload = models.ImageField(upload_to='upload')
```

views.py

```
   @login_required(login_url="login/")
    def carlist(request):
        Myform = MyModelForm(user=request.user)
        return render(request,'about.html',{'Myform':Myform})
```

select django form :

```
class MyModelForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # extract "user" from kwrags (passed upon form init)
        if 'user' in kwargs:
            self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # generate the choices as (display, value). 
        # Display is the one that'll be shown to user, value is 
        # the one that'll be sent upon submitting 
        # (the "value" attribute of <option>)
        choices = MyModel.objects.filter(user=self.user).values_list('upload', 'id')
        self.fields['upload'].widget = Select(choices=choices)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('upload',)
```

html :

```
<form class="" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
  {{ Myform}}
<input type="submit" name="" value="Submit">
```

for example `Myform` now has a list of user images, which is correct but after that i need the selected images from the form.

Can do it that with my code or not?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it with your code. In your view, you can get it as:

```
class MyView(View):
     def post(self, request):
         form = MyModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
         if form.is_valid():
              upload_inst = form.cleaned_data['upload']
              ...
```

This will give you the selected image from the form.

If you want to have multiple images being selected, you could try the following:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-multiselectfield/
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-select-multiple-field/